# python multimdimensional sorting, combined values

Tags: python, list, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional list where I would like to sort on a combined weighting of two numeric elements, example, of results using: `sorted(results, key=operator.itemgetter(2,3))`

```
[..,1,34]
...
...
[..,10,2]
[..,11,1]
[..,13,3]
[..,13,3]
[..,13,3]
[..,16,1]
[..,29,1]
```

The problem with itemgetter is that is first sorts by element 2, then by element 3, where
I would like to have the 13,3 at the top/bottom (dependent on asc/desc sort).

Is this possible and if so how.

Many thanks

Edit 1.

Sorry for being obtuse, I am processing dom data, results from search pages, it's a generic search engine searcher, so to speak.

What I am doing is finding the a and div tags, then I create a count how many items a particular class or id occurs the the div/a tag, this is element 2, then I rescan the list of found tags again and see what other class/id's for the tags match the total for the current tag being processed, thus in this case item 13,3 has 13 matches for class/id for that type of tag, and 3 denotes that there are 3 other tags with class/id's that occur the same amount of times, hence why I wish to sort like that, and no, it is not a dict, it's definitely a list.

Thank you.

Comment: You **do not** have a multidimensional list/dict. You have a dict which has tuple keys. That's very different since it means e.g. the keys `(0,1)` and `(0,2)` have as much in common as `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Why should 13,3 be at the top or bottom? Neither 13 nor 3 is either the smallest or largest value.

Comment: Can you make your question clearer?  What exactly is the sorting algorithm you'd like to use?  e.g., why would (13,3) be at the top?

Comment: Why do you think that `[..,13,3]` should be at the top/bottom?

Comment: What do you mean by "combined weighting"?

Answer (score 2):

I'm making a total guess here, given lack of any other explanation, and assuming what you're actually trying to do is sort by the **product** of the last two keys in your list, secondarily sorted by magnitude of the **first element in the product**.  That's the only explanation I can come up with offhand for why `(13,3)` would be the top result.

In that case, you'd be looking for something like this:

```
sorted(results, key=lambda x: (x[-2]*x[-1], x[-2]), reverse=True)
```

That would give you the following sort:

```
[[13, 3], [13, 3], [13, 3], [1, 34], [29, 1], [10, 2], [16, 1], [11, 1]]
```

**Alternatively,** if what you're actually looking for here is to have the results ordered by the number of times they appear in your list, we can use a  `collections.Counter`.  Unfortunately, lists aren't hashable, so we'll cheat a bit and convert them to tuples to use as the keys.  There are ways around this, but this is the simplest way for me for now to demonstrate what I'm talking about.

```
import collections, json
def sort_results(results):
    c = collections.Counter([tuple(k) for k in results])
    return sorted(c, key=lambda x: c[x], reverse=True)
```

This gets you:

```
[(13, 3), (1, 34), (16, 1), (29, 1), (11, 1), (10, 2)]
```

*Thanks **J.F. Sebastian** for pointing out that tuples could be used instead of `str`!*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's what I was looking for, I'm pretty good with Python, but I'm still learning the multitude of functions available. Code's nearly finished, just a few tidy ups and testing and I'll have a generic search engine searcher, p.s as an aside, I'm not reinventing the wheel, just couldn't find a utility that did exactly what I needed it to

Comment: you could use `tuple` instead of `str` to avoid `json.loads` at the end: `Counter(map(tuple, results))` assuming 2D-list. Also `key=c.get` might work instead of the lambda.

Comment: @J.F. Thanks, didn't realize that tuples were hashable.  Will update.  And I was thinking about using something like c.get, but I just think the `lambda` makes it clearer what's going on, honestly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write whatever function you want as the key function. For example, if you wanted to sort by the sum of the second and third elements:

```py
def keyfunc(item):
    return sum(operator.itemgetter(2, 3)(item))

sorted(results, key=keyfunc)
```

So if you used this function as your `keyfunc`, the item with 13 as the second element 3 as the third element of the list would be sorted as though it were the value 16.

It's not clear how you want to sort these elements, but you can change the body of `keyfunc` to perform whatever operation you'd like.

Comment: `keyfunc()` might not be enough if "combined weighting" involves more than one item, see `collections.Counter` example in [`@jdotjdot's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14035058/4279)